# C# window application: "MyApplication.vshost.exe" Continuous coming at task manager

Tags: c#, .net

In my c# windows application whenever I open my solution in visual studio 2008, than "MyApplication.vshost.exe" is always visible at window task manager--> Process tab.

When i tried to kill that, it again reappear at Process tab.

I am not getting for what vshost.exe created? and why its not getting removed from task manager?
How can we remove it?

Comment: This setting is true, by default. The vshost.exe will appear ONLY if the IDE is running. The process will get spawned as you open the project. The process will exit when the IDE or project closes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can read more about [vshost.exe on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331(VS.80).aspx).

> The hosting process is a feature in Visual Studio 2005 that improves debugging performance, enables partial trust debugging, and enables design time expression evaluation. The hosting process files contain vshost in the file name and are placed in the output folder of your project.

Answer (score 18):

The vshost.exe feature was introduced with VS2005.

The purpose of it is mostly to make debugging launch quicker - basically there's already a process with the framework running, just ready to load your application as soon as you want it to.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx) and [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/dtemp/archive/2004/08/17/215764.aspx) for more information.

You can stop the *.vshost.exe from spawning by -

Right clicking `MyProject` -> `Properties` -> `Debug` tab, and unchecking the `Enable the Visual Studio hosting process` checkbox.

Comment: Hi, Ideally what this setting should be? because at another PC its checked and vshost.exe doesn't appear at task manager.

But at problem PC, the setting is checked and vshost.exe appears at task manager?

Comment: +1 My project wouldn't compile because MyProject.exe in Debug folder couldn't be written to, it couldn't be written to because MyProject.vshost.exe was running and restarted each time I killed it from Task manager. Microsoft support offered exactly nothing on this. Instead of closing the solution and starting it again (which takes ages in my case) I unchecked it and debug could be started again (I checked it again later), your solution resolved this temporary glitch.

Comment: this 'temporary glitch' is a consistent pain debugging multi-threaded program utilizing system.net.sockets ..

Answer (score 5):

You can disable this. Right click on the project, select properties and go to the Debug tab. In there you can uncheck the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" check box