# Finding the thread which is keeping the application from closing

Tags: c#

I'm having a big issue with a project I'm working on.
When it's running it might be running good for two hours and then suddenly it starts crashing quite quite a lot without doing anything different.

when this happens, the entire application hangs and I can't close the program. All of the other applications on my pc keep working normally.

The only way to get rid of that process and to restart it again, is to reboot the pc. This is obviously very annoying. When it crashes and I look at the Task Manager, I see that the vshost.exe*32 is still running with only 1 handle and 1 thread which appearantly can't be terminated other then by rebooting.

Is there a way for me to see which thread this is, to give me a clue as in what direction I need to start looking to solve this issue or to find the problem?

The crashes are happening at various points when using the software, so it's never in the same place.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Cainnech

Comment: very hard to tell why it's crashing without seeing any code..
Perhaps you are doing something incorrectly in your code.. for example you could have some `StackOverFlow` Errors, you may not be disposing of Object's Correctly.. there can be a number of things that are going wrong... Perhaps it's your coded logic that's causing the problem.. have you `Debugged the Code..` are you familiar with Debugging, Error Handling / Error Trapping / Error reporting.....etc...?

Comment: Very hard to determine what's going on without seeing any real code very difficult to answer could be a number of things

Comment: Showing the code is difficult as it's over 5000 lines. The application does not go into debugging mode. It just locks up. So it looks like it's stuck in a sort of endless loop or something. I'm using multiple threads to perform certain tasks but they seem to be working fine. I'm also using an external dll to send out midi-signals. So maybe the problem is in there? I'm generating logs to try to determine where the issue is happening but those don't give me clear answers either. The problem is that I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: can you run the program in visual studio? if so: run it! wait for it to crash. if you're lucky you'll see the exception that is thrown. if the application just runs without doing nothing, click on the pause icon (or in the menu: DEBUG/Break all) then visual studio will focus on the line of code that is currently executed. this could be helpful to determin, where your app is endlessly residing :)

Comment: I'm running the application only from Visual Studio. The problem is when it crashes, it doesn't throw any exceptions. It just blocks. Even when I stop debugging the solution, the vshost.exe just keeps on going and can't be stopped. I haven't tried the pause-suggestion. I will try to do so but it might take a while before it crashes again.

Comment: maybe this helps as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221205/c-sharp-window-application-myapplication-vshost-exe-continuous-comming-at-tas

Comment: So I've managed to make it crash again. However I can't pause Visual Studio because I don't have the pause button. Even the Debug>Break all is not present. I should tell you that I'm still on  VS2010...

Comment: I have a vague recollection of some bug in Visual Studio, in which a crash in a certain kind of program hangs the whole IDE (don't recall if it required reboot). Have you tried a newer version of Visual Studio? Even one of the Express versions? In any case, your problem description is very vague...I don't see how anyone else would be able to figure it out. It's not even clear that your "crash" is really some kind of a fault as opposed to something simply getting stuck in an infinite loop, deadlock, or something similar.